# Why is modal popup reloading my sharepoint page?

Tags: modal-dialog

I am pretty new to HTML/CSS and know nothing about Javascript. On my sharepoint page I want visitors to be able to click on a link and for it to open a popup with just a title and text. After doing some googling I found the perfect code! It works perfectly when I run it in Brackets, but when I try to open it in sharepoint it doesn't work. I can click on it, it opens the popup, but after about 1 second the page reloads and the modal disappears. Like I said it works perfectly in Brackets so maybe sharepoint is blocking it in some way? I will add my code below. Thank you!

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button does not have a type defined. Some browsers default button elements to have type=submit. Your button may be acting as a 'Submit' button which is causing the browser to attempt to submit the web page.

Try declaring your button specifically as just a button. To do so, add the 'type' attribute to the button and define the type as 'button'.

ie:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```